# Charset in JTextPane which using AdvancedRTFEditorKit

Tags: java, character-encoding, jtextpane

I'm having some problems with charset encodings. I'm using AdvancedRTFEditorKit (free closed source library: http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html).

If I copy some special characters (ěščřžýáíé) from MS Word and paste them into sample delivered with AdvancedRtfEditorKit library, everything works fine. But if I do the same with my really simple SSCCE which uses AdvancedRTFEditorKit, then they appear as just rectangles. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

This problem only occurs with MS Office products. LibreOffice works fine.

My SSCCE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(350, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.setEditorKit(new AdvancedRTFEditorKit());

    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many changes in my code I figured out there isn't any problem with my app. My problem was just running app directly from NetBeans IDE. I don't know why, but IDE somehow encode/decode interaction with OS.